# Datatables export(TableTools) after filter/search

Tags: css, datatables

I will very much like to put the export function i DataTables to be beside the filter option(se images)

But tried to play with sDom but with out luck:

```
"sDom": 'l<"clear"Tf>rtip',
```

[DataTable sDom](http://datatables.net/usage/options#sDom)

It look like they both use css "float": right. Any suggestion to move the export function so it all stay on one line?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I solve this problem was, by changing the CSS.

```
.dataTables_filter {
    /*
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    */
    width: 43%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
}
```

And of course add the TableTool like this:

```
"sDom": 'lfTrtip'
```

Result:
[image]